# how to concatenate two lists in python with numbers and strings?

Tags: python, python-3.x, list, concatenation

i want to merge two lists together, but not one after the other

```
list1=[1,2,3,4]
list2=[a,b,c,d,e,f]
```

and the output should be

```
list3=[1a,2b,3c,4d,e,f]
```

Comment: you need to convert list2 into `string format`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [`itertools.zip_longest`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html#itertools.zip_longest) to iterate over lists of uneven length, and provide a default value (`fillvalue`) for the missing elements.

```
from itertools import zip_longest

list1 = [1, 2, 3, 4]
list2 = ["a", "b", "c", "d", "e", "f"]

res = [f"{a}{b}" for a, b in zip_longest(list1, list2, fillvalue="")]
print(res)
```

**Output**

```
['1a', '2b', '3c', '4d', 'e', 'f']
```

The expression `f"{a}{b}"` is known as an [f-string](https://realpython.com/python-f-strings/) and is used to *format* strings.